# Which heroku dynos is better for 1500+ active users on application?

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, dyno

I have deployed my nodeJS backend on Heroku Hobby dynos. There are 1500+ active users. So the API response time is very slow some times, Please help to figure out which dynos is better for backend deployement.

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and then [ask]. This is too broad. It's impossible to answer without _way_ more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always depends on your application. What type of operations and workload are you handling in your API, do you have any synchronous/blocking operation? Is there a lot of I/O involved? More information about what you are trying to achieve would be helpful to give a better recommendation.

One best practice for Node.js is to scale horizontally, this means, having multiple small servers to handle traffic instead of having one big server (vertical scaling). So, a good recommendation is to scale using multiples dynos, try to scale to 2 and measure again to see if it fits your performance needs.

Some recommended readings:

- [Good practices for high-performance and scalable Node.js applications](https://medium.com/iquii/good-practices-for-high-performance-and-scalable-node-js-applications-part-1-3-bb06b6204197)
- [Optimizing Node.js Application Concurrency](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-concurrency)

Comment: [Please don't answer off-topic questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276637/354577)

Comment: Thanks, will take it into account for the next time